# pygame module is not working in python 3.4.2

Tags: python, pygame

Pygame module is installed but not working.

`ImportError: No module named 'pygame.locals'; 'pygame' is not a package`

it worked when I import it in idle without creating a file but not working when .py file is executed through interpreter

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're not using `pygame.py` as a script filename. It will prevent the import of `pygame` module you want.

Rename the file not to conflict. Also make sure there's no remaning `pygame.pyc` file.

Comment: @RajeevMalik, Isn't your file name `"pygame.py"`?